# How to use RXJS to refresh stale but active data

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of observables as a data store and I want to make sure ones that are hot don't go stale. For example, if there are no subscribers to an observeable, then I don't need to update it, but if there are subscribers then it shouldn't go more than 5 minutes without an update.

[timeout](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timeout) seems to be what I want, but I don't want it to error out, I just want to run code when it times out (similar to `tap`). [timeoutwith](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timeoutWith) is closer still because I can replace it with an observable. However, it doesn't seem 'right' and after one timeout, the replacement observable won't have the `timeoutWidth` operator attached.

```
function getData(index){
    return database[index].pipe(timeoutWith(5*60*1000, database[index]))
}
```

One approach I just thought of is to add a recursive `addTimeout` method but this feels hacky:

```
private addTimeout(obs:Observable<any>, time:number):Observable<any>{
    return obs.pipe(timeoutWith(time,this.addTimeout(obs,time)));
  }
```

EDIT, adding code using timeout/retry:

```
const staleDataTime = 5*60*1000; // 5 minutes


// bhs makes it so you can update the value manually whenever you want
let bhs = new BehaviorSubject<Summary>(initialSummary);

// This will reset bhs after the timeout
bhs.pipe(timeout(staleDataTime)).subscribe(success=>null,err=>bhs.next(null));


let obs = bhs.pipe(
   switchMap(val=>val?of(val):this.retreiveSummary(filter)),
   timeout(staleDataTime),
   retry(),
   distinctUntilChanged((a:Summary,b:Summary) => a.count==b.count && a.sum == b.sum),      
   share()
);

obs.subscribe(val=>console.log("obs val: ", val));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a custom operator for this because you can use `timeout()` and `retry()`:

```
return database[index].pipe(
  timeoutWith(5 * 60 * 1000),
  retry(),
);
```

`retry()` will resubscribe to its source if it emits an error. However, this all is expecting that `database[index]` refreshes always when you subscribe to it.

Comment: It took me forever, but I was ultimately able to get it working. Updated my question with my code

Answer (score 1):

I realized this wasn't too hard to do with a custom operator

```
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


export const tapTimeout = (onTimeout:(()=>any), delay:number) => {
    let timeout = window.setTimeout(onTimeout, delay);
    return pipe(tap(x=> {
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = window.setTimeout(onTimeout,delay);
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an RX operator way of doing this

```
obs.pipe(
    switchMap(()=>timer(5*60*1000).pipe(
       tap(_=>..dosomething),
       repeat())
  )
)
```